# sysprep generalize when upgrading motherboard or changing SATA mode

Tags: windows, sata, sysprep

This is my first post here and was looking for a possible solution to my question.

I have been using sysprep generalize when upgrading motherboards, or switching SATA mode operations from IDE - AHCI - RAID. This is working fine, howerver I have to be able to boot into Windows. If I have a system whose motherboard will not POST, this will not work. It is usually a hit or miss whether Windows will boot depending on the drivers installed for the SATA controller.

Which leads me to my question - Is there a way to run sysprep, or something similar to change SATA mode without access to the Windows interface?

Comment: Which OS? If it is win 7 (tested) or win8/vasta (untested by me) then the switch between SATA and IDE can be done by editing the registry. There are liveCDs with registry editors on them. Which would allow you to work around a small part of your question. I am looking forward to someone who can answer it completely with a 'sure, just do this and this and that and it will always work!'.

Comment: Honestly, any OS (XP, VISTA, 7, 8) .. they are all affected by this issue

Comment: I know the registry workaround for IDE/AHCI does not work for XP. (It needs its drivers changed). 7 comes with drivers for ancient_IDE and AHCI and it is just a question of enabling them. Other than that specific small part: Aye.